# отправка данных ajax

Tags: php, opencart

Подскажите, как в opencart2 принять данные в модель, у меня есть форма

```
 <form action="" method="post">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
          <thead class="thin-border-bottom">
          <tr>
            <th style="width: 10%;">
              <i class="ace-icon fa fa-caret-right blue"></i><?php echo $text_id ;?>
            </th>
            <th>
              <i class="ace-icon fa fa-caret-right blue"></i><?php echo $text_name_category ;?>
            </th>

            <th class="hidden-480">
              <i class="ace-icon fa fa-caret-right blue"></i><?php echo $text_status_category ;?>
            </th>
            <th style="width: 8%">
              <i class="ace-icon fa fa-caret-right blue"></i><?php echo "Изменить" ;?>
            </th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <?php foreach ($category as $category){ ?>
          <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $category['category_id']?></td>
            <input type="hidden" name="category_id" id="category_id"  value="<?php echo $category['category_id'];?>">

            <td><?php echo $category['name'];?></td>
            <?php if($category['status'] == 1){ ?>
            <td class="hidden-480">
              <span class="label label-info arrowed-right arrowed-in"><?php echo $text_on ;?></span>
            </td>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <td class="hidden-480">
              <span class="label label-info arrowed-right arrowed-in"><?php echo $text_off ;?></span>
            </td>
            <?php } ?>
            <td>
              <center><button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" id="<?php echo $category['category_id'];?>" type="button" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#myEdit" onclick="give(this.id)" >
                <i class="ace-icon fa fa-edit bigger-120"></i>
                <span class="bigger-110"></span>
                </button></center>
            </td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
          <?php } ?>
        </table>
      </form>
```

так я получаю id категории

```
<script>
function give(val) {
    var obj = document.getElementById('block');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/index.php?route=product/category',
        data: val,
        success: function (data) {
           console.log(val);
        }
    });

}
```

в консоле при нажатие на кнопку у меня приходят id 85, 82 и т.д. Как записать полученные данные не могу понять, когда в контролере я делал print_r($_POST), ничего не происходит, и я не знаю, что приходит в post-e, подскажите, как это можно сделать.

Comment: Попробуй `data: 'id='+val`

Comment: Тогда должно прийти $_POST['id'], а это можно как то посмотреть ?

Comment: Можете подробней объяснить

Comment: Вы работаете с opencart?

Comment: да  с opencart? .........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуй либо в php складывать полученный результат в файл, либо когда делаешь ajax-запрос в хроме (например) есть inspector - в нем на вкладке networking можно смотреть все запросы и ответы в том числе XHR.

Comment: Да я получаю Form data  id:82  при нажатие на кнопку, в модели делаю 
 `$id = isset($this->request->post['id']);
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category WHERE category_id = '" .$id. "'");  return $query->row;`               и проверка не срабатывает я не могу понять почему?

Comment: $id = isset($this->request->post['id']) <-- здесь $id будет либо true либо false. SQL-запрос будет выглядеть примерно так: SELECT * FROM prefix_category WHERE category_id = 'true'

Comment: А как же сделать что бы приходило значение, вывод данных будет отображаться только если туда придет нужный id ?

Comment: @Рома Капиошка вы аяксом дёргаете контроллер, а не модель.

Comment: Что то не выходит в контролере  `$this->model_product_category->getCategoryId(isset($this->request->post['id']));` а в модели `   $id = isset($this->request->post['id'])?$this->request->post['id']:null;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category";

        if($id){
            $sql .=" WHERE region_id = '" . $id . "'";
        }
        $query = $this->db->query( $sql );

        return $query->rows;` и ошибка